# Backup my data from broken ubuntu

Tags: gnome, kernel

During upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 I have lost power. I cant make recovery mode or grap and when try to boot from life CD I got this message :

```
cannot mount  /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem)
```

I only want copy my data.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Insert any Ubuntu LiveCD and choose `Try Ubuntu without installing` or something like that what you get. Then from the live session take backup of your personal files.